# Programmatically loading parse images and text into linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, parse-platform

I am trying to create a list of items followed by their name and caloric value in a similar way to the image below.
[image: example](https://imgur.com/a/QdkqQiy)]
However I am trying to do this while getting all my data from Parse. I have got it down for the most part but I have been stuck for hours trying to programatically add these two text views and image one after the other (text then view) as I loop through them.
I have been skeptical to make major changes to the code as I am not very proficient with android, however from what I have looked at so far my case seems to be unique in the sense that it involves both Parse and using textviews and imageviews together.

Below is what I've got so far on this activity:

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdminProductsListActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Class**

```
    package com.parse.starter;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseFile;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;

    import java.util.List;

    public class AdminProductsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        LinearLayout linLayout;
        Intent intent;
        String name;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView itemCalories;
        ImageView imageView;



    public void showMain() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    public void addNewProduct() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNewProductActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("shop", name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.new_admin_settings_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.newItem){
            ParseUser.logOut();
            addNewProduct();

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout){
            ParseUser.logOut();

            showMain();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_products_list);
        intent = getIntent();
        name = intent.getStringExtra("username");


        linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout);

        setTitle(name);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Product");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", name);
        query.orderByDescending("objectID");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null && list.size() > 0){
                    for (ParseObject object : list){
                        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("image");

                        //if (itemName != null && itemCalories != null){
                            itemName = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            itemName.setText(object.getString("name"));
                            itemName.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            itemCalories = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            itemCalories.setText(object.getString("calories") + " kcal");
                            itemCalories.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            linLayout.addView(itemCalories);
                            linLayout.addView(itemName);



                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null && bytes != null){
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                    ));

                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                                    linLayout.addView(imageView);


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Right now what happens is all the text goes to the top and images goes to the bottom. I've also tried doing this:

```
file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null && bytes != null){
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                ));

                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                                linLayout.addView(imageView);
                                linLayout.addView(itemCalories);
                                linLayout.addView(itemName);
```

But then I get this Error:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

and none of the answers to this error that I found seem to be helpful in this situation.

Long story short, I'm not even looking for something super complex or for it to look good, I am just a beginner. I just want to load the textviews and then the imageview one after the other, just like in the image, while using parse.

Any ideas?

Comment: if the text and image are always paired/ related content. I'd create a view that takes some text and image and then make a list of those views.

Comment: @mavriksc thanks for the reply, but like I said, I am a bit new to this. Any suggestions on how I should go about doing that? Or resources that I could check?

Comment: maybe a list of Cards will work.